# Terraform lookup function ignoring variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an AWS target group along with health checks and stickiness arguments. I make use of `lookup` function in terraform for this.

`main.tf` file:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "this" {

  port = lookup(var.target_groups, "port", null)
  protocol = (lookup(var.target_groups, "protocol", null))
  target_type = lookup(var.target_groups, "target_type", null)
  deregistration_delay = lookup(var.target_groups, "deregistration_delay", null)
  slow_start = lookup(var.target_groups, "slow_start", null)


  dynamic "health_check" {
    for_each = var.target_groups
    content {
      enabled = lookup(health_check.value, "enabled", null)
      protocol = lookup(health_check.value, "protocol", null)
      path = lookup(health_check.value, "path", null)
      port = lookup(health_check.value, "port", null)
      healthy_threshold = lookup(health_check.value, "healthy_threshold", null)
      unhealthy_threshold = lookup(health_check.value, "unhealthy_threshold", null)
      timeout = lookup(health_check.value, "timeout", null)
      interval = lookup(health_check.value, "interval", null)
      matcher = lookup(health_check.value, "matcher", null)
    }
  }

  dynamic "stickiness" {
    for_each = var.target_groups
    content {
      type = lookup(stickiness.value, "type", "lb_cookie")
      cookie_duration = lookup(stickiness.value, "cookie_duration", null)
      enabled = lookup(stickiness.value, "enabled", null)
    }
  }
}
```

`variables.tf` file:

```
variable "target_groups" {
  default     = {
    "default values" = {
      port = 80
      protocol = "HTTP"
      target_type = "instance"
      deregistration_delay = 300
      slow_start = 0
      "health_check" = {
        enabled = true
        protocol = "HTTP"
        path = "/"
        port = "traffic-port"
        healthy_threshold = 5
        unhealthy_threshold = 2
        timeout = 5
        interval = 30
        matcher = "200"
      }
      "stickiness" = {
        type = "lb_cookie"
        cookie_duration = 86400
        enabled = false
      }
    }
  }
  type = any
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` terraform assigns all the default values for health checks and for stickiness block, meaning terraform `lookup` is completely ignoring the `variables.tf` file. Eg. value for `healthy_threshold = 5` but `terraform plan` set its default value i.e, 3.

What changes or improvements are required in `variables.tf` file as I am not able to get how to set variables correctly for the `lookup` functions

Comment: Your data structure doesn't support the access pattern you have in your code. You are looking for `var.target_groups["port"]` when your data structure looks like `var.target_groups["default values"]["port"]`.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR can you please provide a quick fix for the above files. Is the `variables.tf` file correct?

Comment: Your data structure probably needs rethinking.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have tried removing `default value` but it is giving me this error:
`Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
 argument.` which means I need a key which is `default value`

Comment: You should edit your question to include any changes you make and the errors you get from running that.